# Showing a collection of sets forms a semiring

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> **Definition:** A nonempty collection $S$ of subsets of $X$ is a *semiring* if for any two sets
> $A,B\in S$,
> $$A\cap B\in S\tag{a}$$
> and there is a finite disjoint collection $\{s_k\}_{k=1}^{n}$ with $s_k\in S$, so that
> $$A\setminus B = \bigcup_{k=1}^{n}s_k\tag{b}$$

> **Question:** Consider the collection $S = \{\emptyset, [0, 1], [0, 3], [2, 3]\}$ of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. I want to show that $S$ forms a semiring.

For property $(a)$; $\emptyset$ intersected with any set in $S$ is again $\emptyset$ which is in $S$, $[0,1]$ intersected with any set in $S$ is either the $\emptyset$ or $[0,1]$ both are in $S$, $[0,3]$ intersected with any set in $S$ is either the $\emptyset$ or $[0,1]$ or $[2,3]$ all in $S$, and lasty $[2,3]$ intersected with any set in $S$ is either the $\emptyset$ or $[2,3]$ all in $S$. Therefore, property $(a)$ holds.

For property $(b)$; $\emptyset$ set-minus any set in $S$ is empty hence the finite disjoint collection
$\{\emptyset\}$ works, $[0,1]$ set-minus any set in $S$ is either $\emptyset$ or $[0,1]$ hence the finite disjoint collection $\{\emptyset\}$ or $\{[0,1]\}$ works respectively, $[0,3]$ set-minus any set in $S$ is either $[0,3]$ or $[2,3]$ or $[0,1]$ hence the finite disjoint collection $\{[0,3]\}$ or $\{[2,3]\}$ or $\{[0,1]\}$ works respectively, and lastly $[2,3]$ set-minus any set in $S$ is either $[2,3]$ or $[0,1]$ hence the finite disjoint collection $\{[2,3]\}$ or $\{[0,1]\}$ works respectively.

---

My question is *simply*, is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S = \{\emptyset, [0, 1], [0, 3], [2, 3]\}$ of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ is **not** a semiring.

Note that $[0,3] \setminus [0,1] = (1,3]$ and $(1,3]$  can not be written as a finite union of elements in $S$.

Also, $[0,3] \setminus [2,3] = [0,2)$ and $[0,2)$  can not be written as a finite union of elements in $S$.

Regarding your argument:

You wrote "$[0,3]$ set-minus any set in $S$ is either $[0,3]$ or $[2,3]$ or $[0,1]$". This is not true.

You also wrote "$[2,3]$ set-minus any set in $S$ is either $[2,3]$ or $[0,1]$. That is incorrect. The right statement would be "$[2,3]$ set-minus any set in $S$ is either $\emptyset$ or $[2,3]$.

Comment: True. By any chance do you have the Royden’s text on real analysis?

Comment: On page 357, problem 26 asks to show that a set function $\mu$ is a premeasure on this collection $S$. However, if $S$ is not a semiring (which now I see that it is not), how does one show that $\mu$ is a premeasure, as to my knowledge a premeasure is defined only on a semiring?

Comment: @D.Math Yes, I have. How could I help you?

Comment: @D.Math On page 353, Royden defines premeasure on any collection of subsets. The next step is to show that with such broad definition the Carathéory measure induced by the premeasure may not be an extension of the premeasure. This is the goal of problems 25 and 26.  Then, Royden will go to impose conditions on the collection of subsets, to ensure that  the Carathéory measure induced by the premeasure is an extension of the premeasure.

Comment: @D.Math Most book do not follow Royden's path and they start already requiring  the collection of subsets to be a semiring.

Comment: Ah, okay. My professor was requiring the collection of subsets to be a semiring but assigned this problem from Royden, which clearly leads to some confusion. Thanks!

Comment: To ask one more thing: So, the on page 357, problem 26 the answer would be that $\mu$ cannot be extended to a measure since the collection of sets $S$ do not for a semiring?

Comment: @D.Math  No. You should use definition of premeasure as it is on page 353 and  determine the Carathéodory measure induced by the premeasure and show that such measure is not an extension of the premeasure.

Comment: How does one determine the Carathéodory measure induced by the premeasure?

Comment: @D.Math ,  For problem 26 on page 357, you need: Step 1. Prove that $\mu$ is a premeasure ( definition of premeasure on page 353, definition of finitely additive on page 352, definition of countably monotone on page 346).  Step 2. Find the outer measure induced by $\mu$ (definition of outer measure on page 346, definition of outer measure induced by $\mu$ on page 350, in Theorem 9). Continue...

Comment: @D.Math , Step 3 Find the  measurable set with respect to the outer measure (definition on page 347). The set of measurable sets is a $\sigma$-algebra (Theorem 8 on page 349) and the outer measure restricted to such $\sigma$-algebra is a a complete measure (Theorem 8 on page 349 again), it is the Carathéodory measure induced by the premeasure $\mu$.

Comment: Thank you very much!